# Linear regression with stochastic gradient descent p-values

Tags: regression, p-value, descriptive-statistics, gradient-descent, multivariate-regression

Is there any way to get summary statistics (p-value specifically) for the results of a multivariate linear regression ($y = X\beta + \epsilon)$ using gradient descent? Most online library implementations give me $\beta$, but how can I find p-value for each of the $\beta_i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First:  what is a p-value?  It's the probability that the observed statistic would have been observed under the null hypothesis.

So, what is your hypothesis?  Typically with OLS regression, the null hypothesis is that your coefficients are equal to zero.

In any given sample, they will never be exactly zero.  But any sample is just that, a sample.

The linear regression model is

$$
y = X\beta + \epsilon
$$

$\beta$ is unknown.  Typically people estimate it with $(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty$, which can be shown to minimize the sum of squares, which is also the gradient descent objective.  If $X$ is well-conditioned, then this solution is unique.  Which is to say that a good gradient descent algorithm will find something equivalent to this solution if you let it converge.

So if your estimator is 
$$
(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty
$$
$$
(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\hat\beta + \hat\epsilon)
$$
Its variance becomes: (try to figure out what step I skipped)
$$
(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\hat\epsilon\hat\epsilon^TX(X^TX)^{-1}
$$
which under homoskedastisity assumptions reduces to 
$$
\hat\sigma^2_\epsilon(X^TX)^{-1}
$$
This is the matrix of the variance of the paramter estimators.  The p-values are based on their diagonals.

To end my pedantry and get to your actual question:  you can't get p-values analytically unless your gradient descent has converged and your solution is equivalent to the closed-form solution.  Otherwise, how could you possibly know what the variance of your estimator would be in different samples?  You could bootstrap your grandient descent process, but that'd be pretty silly, probably.

Comment: I follow your reasoning, but am still slightly confused where the $\sigma^2$ comes from, and how to find it.

Comment: $\hat\epsilon\hat\epsilon^T$ is a $N\times N$ matrix.  If every observation is drawn from the same distribution, then it reduces to a variance times an identity matrix.  You get sigma from the commutative property.

Comment: Also, up where I skipped a step:  the stepped skip depends on the unbiasedness of the OLS estimator.  Your non-converged gradient descent algorithm won't be unbiased.  That means that your variance term carries around a bunch of baggage.

Comment: Assuming SGD has converged and my solution is very close to closed form solution, how could I then go about getting the p-value? Essentially what information would I need to store when I "lose" a sample/batch and move on to the next one

Comment: The variance matrix of the parameter estimators has the variances of the coefs on the diagonal.  You can compute the matrix, take the diagonal, and get t-statistics by dividing the standard deviations by the coefs.  P value from t stat is straightforward.  

Here's the real question:  why use SGD and not closed form-OLS?  Presumably it's because you've got a huge dataset and don't want to evaluate $(X^TX)^{-1}$.  If that's your problem, you can't get p-values the standard way.  

But if you've got a huge dataset and you're just running a linear regression, why not just subample?

Comment: You're correct in assuming my reason- the dataset im working with is too large to load into memory. Random sampling is something I have to avoid because its a genetics dataset, so many 'things' are rare. Evaluating $(X^tX)^-1$ isn't an issue in terms of runtime- its an issue in terms of memory. To solve it, I want to be able to run a lin regression on a subset (say 1/10 of the samples), store some information, and then update that information with the next batch of samples, such that after 10 batches I have the same $\beta$ and p-value as I would if I had ran an OLS with all samples at once.

Comment: I don't immediately know of an algorithm that does that reliably. If it was simple you'd think it'd ship with whatever SGD ols library you're using.